# asp.net core Identity Jwt Bearer deactivate user

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, jwt

On our web api auth mechanism we issue jwt tokens upon login of a client 
much like described in this article:
https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/03/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-i/

The jwt holds authentication and authorization information as the username and role are incorporated in the form of claims.

AND now we are asked to provide the ability for the application admin to **deactivate** users, meaning that a user that already has some not yet expired token, if deactivated, should be blocked.

I know that in order to achieve that we ll probably have to hit the db for every request and this is not a good practice, but we have already started with jwt and we must stay on that.

Yet, what is the approach that we could follow?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If hitting the db is too expensive, add a caching mechanism. Or use a in-memory db which is populated from the main db outside of the request